# A Question Regarding Uncountable Standard Models of ZFC Where CH is False

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let M be an uncountable standard model of ZFC, let $\frak c$ be the cardinality of the continuum, and let (just for the sake of argument) $\mathfrak c=\aleph_2$.  If one assumes M has 'all' the ordinals, then $L$ is the smallest inner model of ZFC [have I made any mistake here?] and $L \subset M$.  Now according to Cohen, $M$ contains all the countable ordinals so if one restricts one's attention to $L$, $M$ contains all the constructible reals, [is this a faulty reinterpretation of Cohen's assumption of $V=L$?].  Also, if my reasoning is correct, the constructible reals form a continuum of size $\aleph_1$, making it (if one restricts oneself to L) a 'subcontinuum'of M's continuum of $\aleph_2$ (if this line of reasoning is correct, of course...).  Is this line of reasoning correct as it stands, and if so, can the 'L--people' discover that the 'actual' continuum is of size $\aleph_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Apparently my previous answer was bad, for some cryptic reason, so I've written it from scratch.*)

Let's make some order in the things. We have the universe $V$ and $L$ which is the "real" $L$, and $\sf Ord$ is the class of ordinals. Whenever we add a superscript $M$, like $L^M$ or $\mathsf{Ord}^M$ we mean the interpretation of these in a model $M$. Since $L$ is absolute for transitive models, writing $\omega_1^L$ and $\omega_1^{L^M}$ is the same thing, and we can safely use the former notation.

If $M$ is an uncountable transitive model of $\sf ZFC$, then $M\cap\sf Ord=\alpha$ for some uncountable ordinal $\alpha$. It follows that $L_\alpha\subseteq M$, and moreover $L_\alpha=L^M$. In that case indeed every constructible real is in $M$.

Assume that $|M|=\aleph_1$. Then we have several cases.

1. $\omega_1^M=\omega_1^L$, or even better $V$ and $L$ agree on all the cardinals (but not on their exponentiation, as you postulated $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$). The first thing to note that is that $\alpha>\omega_1$. The reason is that $M$ would recognize every countable ordinal as countable (because it is countable in $L$).

   If we assume, for example, that $\sf MA$ holds in $V$, then the argument for the existence of generic filters over $M$ for Cohen forcing follows the same way as it would in the case of countable models. Now we can blow up the continuum inside of $M$, and have $M\models\lnot\sf CH$.
2. $\omega_1^M>\omega_1^L$, so $M$ knows that $\omega_1^L$ is a countable ordinal in $V$, and in which case it is also aware of the fact that $\Bbb R^L$ is nothing but a countable set.

   So it is possible that $M$, while a model of $\sf CH$, or not, is aware that $L$ only has a countable set of real numbers, and therefore $\Bbb R^L$ is **not** a subcontinuum (even not when considering only constructible subsets of it) of $\Bbb R^M$ of size $\aleph_1^M$. Because it is not of size $\aleph_1^M$.

So we can have either case along with $M\models\lnot\sf CH$. So it is impossible to conclude that $\Bbb R^L$ is a subcontinuum of size $\aleph_1^M$ of $\Bbb R^M$, simply because it is possible that it is a countable set.

In either case the "L--people" don't know what is beyond their universe. The question itself is meaningless, as the second case shows.

Finally, let me point out there is an inherent ambiguity in the term "subcontinuum" (in the definition given in the comments). You say that a continuum is a Dedekind-complete linear order. But as you note there is a question of what sets one asks for when interpreting the second-order completeness axiom. And from $M$'s point of view if $N\subseteq M$ and $\Bbb R^N\subsetneq\Bbb R^M$, then $\Bbb R^N$ is not a subcontinuum of $\Bbb R^M$, from the point of view of $M$ itself.

Comment: Thomas, `\aleph` and not `\Aleph`, also keep a space between `\mathbb` and `R`, similarly braces `{}` on the exponents would solve the problem.

Comment: @ Asaf:  Thanks.

Comment: Thomas, it is very hard to read your comment (although with effort I'm sure I can), can you try and repost it? You can use the answer form to test the MathJax before hand. Remember, spaces, braces and lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments.  I'd like to know, however, if it is impossible for $\mathbb R^{L}$ to be a subcontinuum of size $\aleph_1$ of the 'actual' contnuum of size $\aleph_2$ in M.  Under what conditions would this be possible, if at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what a "subcontinuum" is.

Comment: An ordered continuum is a dense linear ordering <X,$\lt$ > such that wherever Y $\subseteq$ X is such that there are x,y $\in$ X with x $\le$ z $\le$ y for all z $\in$ Y, then there is a maximum such x and a minimum such y, in the sense of $\lt$ ( in which case one calls x the infimum of Y and x the supremum of Y).  It should be noted that the supremum and infimum of Y can only be defined relative to a model of set theory (in this case ZFC).  Let $\mathfrac C$ be an ordered continuum in some model M of ZFC.  Let M' be a submodel of M containing the same ordinals and cardinals that M has

Comment: The answer is trivially no. It is not hard to show that every dense, Dedekind-complete suborder of $\Bbb R$ is an interval (with some endpoint combination). If $\Bbb R^L$ has size $\aleph_1$ and $\Bbb R$ has size $\aleph_2$, then that cannot be.

Comment: (also let C be the ordered continuum in some model M of ZFC--forget the gothic script).  A subset C' (C' $\subset$ C is a subcontinuum of C iff C' is an ordered continuum in the model M'.

Comment: @ Asaf: So in your answer, that is why you used the collapse, to preserve Dedekind completeness in M?  Also, is Dedekind completeness absolute?

Comment: @Thomas: No, I used it in order to show a situation where the collection of constructible reals is in fact countable.

Comment: So do there exist uncountable models of ZFC where $\mathbb R^{L}$ is also uncountable?

Comment: @Thomas: Uncountable from what perspective? If $M$ is a transitive model then $L^M$ is a transitive model in which $\Bbb R^L$ is uncountable. It is possible that $M$ is countable and still contains all the constructible reals; and it is possible that $M$ is uncountable and $\Bbb R^L$ is uncountable (in the universe). As I said before, it seems to me that you are trying to gain a shallow understanding of advanced topics in set theory, and it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked, is $\mathbb R^{L}$ uncountable in the uncountable model M?  And when you say "$\mathbb R^{L}$ is uncountable (in the universe)", the universe is V, correct?

Comment: Yes. To your answer, as I mentioned in my previous comments, is "sometimes".

Comment: Since I have no idea what's wrong with the answer, a comment accompanying the downvote would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Regarding your new, improved answer (which I like very much--very helpful), if N is a submodel of M, does M 'know' that N is a submodel of M, and does M  'know' that $\mathbb R^{N}$ is a continuum in N?

Comment: @Thomas: If $N$ is a class of $M$, then yes. $M$ knows that $N$ is a class, and for every axiom of $\sf ZFC$, $M$ knows that $N$ satisfies that axiom; and so $M$ knows what are the real numbers of $N$. It might be that $N$ is not a class of $M$, so the metatheory knows about it, but not $M$ itself. I don't recall any context where that happened, though, so I can't really give you an example off the top of my head when that happens. In the case where $N\models V=L$, then clearly $N$ is a class of $M$.

Comment: Considering your statement that "in either case 'L--people' don't know what is beyond their universe" and considering Carl Mummert's statement in his answer to my question regarding reverse mathematics and V=L ("So V=L is much stronger than is needed to prove the theorems that are usually considered [as theorems of ordinary mathematics]), is it correct to infer that 'ordinary mathematicians' (mathematicians that practice 'ordinary mathematics' as defined in his answer) are 'L--people'?  If not, why not?

Comment: @Thomas: As Carl said, ordinary mathematics is rarely concerned with its set theoretical assumptions.